# how to install python in openshift ( make: *** [sharedmods] Error 1)

Tags: python, makefile, openshift

I want to install python in openshift server by ssh and following the instruction of this site(which 53d02d265973cab243000276 is my user name) :

```
mkdir /var/lib/openshift/53d02d265973cab243000276/app-root/repo/python
cd /var/lib/openshift/53d02d265973cab243000276/app-root/repo/python
wget http://www.python.org/ftp/python/2.7.2/Python-2.7.2.tgz
tar zxfv Python-2.7.2.tgz
rm -rf Python-2.7.2.tgz
find /var/lib/openshift/53d02d265973cab243000276/app-root/repo/python -type d | xargs chmod 0755
cd Python-2.7.2
./configure --prefix=$/var/lib/openshift/53d02d265973cab243000276/app-root/repo/python    make
make install
cd ..
rm -rf Python-2.7.2
```

but when it want to run "make command i get this error ( make: *** [sharedmods] Error 1):

```
[drupal72-ss4ferdowsi2lab.rhcloud.com Python-2.7.2]\> make
gcc -pthread -c -fno-strict-aliasing -g -O2 -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Wstri
ct-prototypes  -I. -IInclude -I./Include   -DPy_BUILD_CORE -o Modules/config.o M
odules/config.c
gcc -pthread -c -fno-strict-aliasing -g -O2 -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Wstri
ct-prototypes  -I. -IInclude -I./Include   -DPy_BUILD_CORE -DPYTHONPATH='":plat-
linux2:lib-tk:lib-old"' \
                -DPREFIX='"var/lib/openshift/53d02d265973cab243000276/app-root/r
epo/python"' \
                -DEXEC_PREFIX='"var/lib/openshift/53d02d265973cab243000276/app-r
oot/repo/python"' \
                -DVERSION='"2.7"' \
                -DVPATH='""' \
                -o Modules/getpath.o ./Modules/getpath.c
gcc -pthread -c -fno-strict-aliasing -g -O2 -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Wstri
ct-prototypes  -I. -IInclude -I./Include   -DPy_BUILD_CORE \
              -DSVNVERSION="\"`LC_ALL=C svnversion .`\"" \
              -DHGVERSION="\"`LC_ALL=C hg id -i .`\"" \
              -DHGTAG="\"`LC_ALL=C hg id -t .`\"" \
              -DHGBRANCH="\"`LC_ALL=C hg id -b .`\"" \
              -o Modules/getbuildinfo.o ./Modules/getbuildinfo.c
abort: repository . not found!
abort: repository . not found!
abort: repository . not found!
rm -f libpython2.7.a
ar rc libpython2.7.a Modules/getbuildinfo.o
ar rc libpython2.7.a Parser/acceler.o Parser/grammar1.o Parser/listnode.o Parser
/node.o Parser/parser.o Parser/parsetok.o Parser/bitset.o Parser/metagrammar.o P
arser/firstsets.o Parser/grammar.o Parser/pgen.o Parser/myreadline.o Parser/toke
nizer.o
ar rc libpython2.7.a Objects/abstract.o Objects/boolobject.o Objects/bufferobjec
t.o Objects/bytes_methods.o Objects/bytearrayobject.o Objects/capsule.o Objects/
cellobject.o Objects/classobject.o Objects/cobject.o Objects/codeobject.o Object
s/complexobject.o Objects/descrobject.o Objects/enumobject.o Objects/exceptions.
o Objects/genobject.o Objects/fileobject.o Objects/floatobject.o Objects/frameob
ject.o Objects/funcobject.o Objects/intobject.o Objects/iterobject.o Objects/lis
tobject.o Objects/longobject.o Objects/dictobject.o Objects/memoryobject.o Objec
ts/methodobject.o Objects/moduleobject.o Objects/object.o Objects/obmalloc.o Obj
ects/rangeobject.o Objects/setobject.o Objects/sliceobject.o Objects/stringobjec
t.o Objects/structseq.o Objects/tupleobject.o Objects/typeobject.o Objects/weakr
efobject.o Objects/unicodeobject.o Objects/unicodectype.o
ar rc libpython2.7.a Python/_warnings.o Python/Python-ast.o Python/asdl.o Python
/ast.o Python/bltinmodule.o Python/ceval.o Python/compile.o Python/codecs.o Pyth
on/errors.o Python/frozen.o Python/frozenmain.o Python/future.o Python/getargs.o
 Python/getcompiler.o Python/getcopyright.o Python/getplatform.o Python/getversi
on.o Python/graminit.o Python/import.o Python/importdl.o Python/marshal.o Python
/modsupport.o Python/mystrtoul.o Python/mysnprintf.o Python/peephole.o Python/py
arena.o Python/pyctype.o Python/pyfpe.o Python/pymath.o Python/pystate.o Python/
pythonrun.o Python/structmember.o Python/symtable.o Python/sysmodule.o Python/tr
aceback.o Python/getopt.o Python/pystrcmp.o Python/pystrtod.o Python/dtoa.o Pyth
on/formatter_unicode.o Python/formatter_string.o Python/dynload_shlib.o   Python
/thread.o
ar rc libpython2.7.a Modules/config.o Modules/getpath.o Modules/main.o Modules/g
cmodule.o
ar rc libpython2.7.a Modules/threadmodule.o  Modules/signalmodule.o  Modules/pos
ixmodule.o  Modules/errnomodule.o  Modules/pwdmodule.o  Modules/_sre.o  Modules/
_codecsmodule.o  Modules/_weakref.o  Modules/zipimport.o  Modules/symtablemodule
.o  Modules/xxsubtype.o
ranlib libpython2.7.a
gcc -pthread  -Xlinker -export-dynamic -o python \
                        Modules/python.o \
                        libpython2.7.a -lpthread -ldl  -lutil   -lm
libpython2.7.a(posixmodule.o): In function `posix_tmpnam':
/var/lib/openshift/53d02d265973cab243000276/app-root/repo/python/Python-2.7.2/./
Modules/posixmodule.c:7370: warning: the use of `tmpnam_r' is dangerous, better
use `mkstemp'
libpython2.7.a(posixmodule.o): In function `posix_tempnam':
/var/lib/openshift/53d02d265973cab243000276/app-root/repo/python/Python-2.7.2/./
Modules/posixmodule.c:7317: warning: the use of `tempnam' is dangerous, better u
se `mkstemp'
running build
running build_ext
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./setup.py", line 2076, in <module>
    main()
  File "./setup.py", line 2071, in main
    'Lib/smtpd.py']
  File "/var/lib/openshift/53d02d265973cab243000276/app-root/runtime/repo/python
/Python-2.7.2/Lib/distutils/core.py", line 152, in setup
    dist.run_commands()
  File "/var/lib/openshift/53d02d265973cab243000276/app-root/runtime/repo/python
/Python-2.7.2/Lib/distutils/dist.py", line 953, in run_commands
    self.run_command(cmd)
  File "/var/lib/openshift/53d02d265973cab243000276/app-root/runtime/repo/python
/Python-2.7.2/Lib/distutils/dist.py", line 972, in run_command
    cmd_obj.run()
  File "/var/lib/openshift/53d02d265973cab243000276/app-root/runtime/repo/python
/Python-2.7.2/Lib/distutils/command/build.py", line 127, in run
    self.run_command(cmd_name)
  File "/var/lib/openshift/53d02d265973cab243000276/app-root/runtime/repo/python
/Python-2.7.2/Lib/distutils/cmd.py", line 326, in run_command
    self.distribution.run_command(command)
  File "/var/lib/openshift/53d02d265973cab243000276/app-root/runtime/repo/python
/Python-2.7.2/Lib/distutils/dist.py", line 972, in run_command
    cmd_obj.run()
  File "/var/lib/openshift/53d02d265973cab243000276/app-root/runtime/repo/python
/Python-2.7.2/Lib/distutils/command/build_ext.py", line 340, in run
    self.build_extensions()
  File "./setup.py", line 152, in build_extensions
    missing = self.detect_modules()
  File "./setup.py", line 1146, in detect_modules
    for arg in sysconfig.get_config_var("CONFIG_ARGS").split()]
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'split'
make: *** [sharedmods] Error 1
[drupal72-ss4ferdowsi2lab.rhcloud.com Python-2.7.2]\>
```

so i think i have problem with user restriction accessing . i hope to install a local python so how is it possible?
thanks a lot for your attention

Comment: The `$` in `--prefix=$/var/lib/openshift/` is incorrect. It does not belong there.

Comment: Python is already installed on the servers.  Why are you trying to install your own version?  We currently support python 2.6, 2.7, and 3.3 I believe.

Comment: I know its installed but for installing new modules i need to install a local python.

Comment: Thanks alot The $ was  incorrect ,my problem solved.